# Catch any call made with a type as a parameter with AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm trying to normalize URIs across an application using AspectJ.  I would like to catch every call that is made to a method passing in a java.net.URI parameter.

A simple pointcut for this would be something like:
    public pointcut uriMethod(URI uri) : call(* *(..)) && args(uri);

However, this seems to only match method signatures with only one argument (the URI).  I can change the args portion to "args(uri, ..)", but this only applies to methods with multiple arguments (losing the single-argument signatures) and only if the first argument is the URI.

Is is possible to construct a point cut to cover all cases:
    public void exampleMethod1(URI uri);
    public void exampleMethod2(URI uri, String s);
    public void exampleMethod3(int i, URI uri);
    public void exampleMethod4(float f, URI uri, short s);

Bonus points if it's possible to capture multiple URIs with the same pointcut:
    public void exampleMethod5(URI uri1, URI uri2);

I'm open to alternative routes, too.  Perhaps I need something based on the URI class itself, not the classes it gets passed into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pointcut expression will satisfy your first condition:

```
execution(* *(..,java.net.URI,..))
```

then in the advise, use joinpoint to navigate through the args, get the arg with URI as the instance - this sort of satisfies your second condition:

```
    @Around("methodsWithURI()")
public void aroundMethodsWithURI(ProceedingJoinPoint joinpoint){
    for(Object objArg: joinpoint.getArgs()){
        if (objArg instanceof URI){
            System.out.println(objArg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Switching to ProceedingJoinPoint.getArgs() from the args() approach did the trick.